# How to get selected text from Gradio Texbox?

Tags: python, gradio

I'm currently working on a project that involves using Gradio to label parts of text data. Specifically, I want to enable users to select (i.e. highlight) a portion of the text inside one textbox and have that selected text automatically appear in another textbox along with some associated values or labels.

While exploring the Gradio documentation, I came across the `gradio.Textbox.select(fn, ···)` method, which allows for actions based on selecting text, but it doesn't seem to provide a way to retrieve the selected text itself or its start and end locations.

For simplicity, let's assume I have two textboxes: `Inp_a` and `Inp_b`. I want to select some text in `Inp_a`, and have that selected text automatically appear in `Inp_b`. Could someone please guide me on how to achieve this functionality?

Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See "Gathering Event Data" in this: https://www.gradio.app/guides/blocks-and-event-listeners#gathering-event-data